# ¿Cómo programar tareas automáticas en PHP sin cron?

Tags: php, mysql

Necesito realizar 3 tareas automáticamente en mi proyecto:

1. Envíar n cantidad de correos mensualmente
2. Insertar automáticamente un registro mensualmente en la BD.
3. Eliminar cada 4 meses los registros antiguos de una tabla de mi BD

Pero tengo un pequeño problema, y es que no lo puedo desarrollar con un Cron, ya que no tengo el permiso para ejecutarlo dentro del servidor ¿Cómo las puedo programar?

Comment: No es necesario duplicar las preguntas: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/326119/tareas-autom%c3%a1ticas-con-php

Comment: Nunca me responderán la otra si la siguen puntuando negativamente...

Comment: ¿Tienes una mejor manera de formularla?

Comment: 1. Muestra algún avance (en código), veo que has intentado algo (en la otra pregunta), 2. Agrega otras etiquetas que puedan atraer a quienes conozcan de temas de servidores y/o sistemas operativos, no solo PHP. 3. NO solicites opinión (en la otra pregunta lo haces). 4. Busca en Google, e idealmente, cita los tutoriales o posts que ya intentaste o consultaste.

Comment: La verdad, no lo he intentado aún, en la otra pregunta puse que "he pensado".., pero gracias, intentaré como me lo mencionas.

Comment: Y cuál es la razón por la que no puedes ejecutarlo, así podemos pensar en opciones

Comment: No tengo permiso en el servidor para ejecutar el cron..., entonces había pensado unas validaciones de fechas, pero ya eliminé la otra pregunta donde tenía una idea de como hacerlo...

Answer (score 2):

Para el caso de la base de datos podrías crear un 'EVENTO'.

No se como tengas tus tablas y que es lo que quieres hacer específicamente pero esta es la estructura general en MariaDB

También debes de habilitarle al servidor esta función

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

```
CREATE [OR REPLACE]
    [DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER | role | CURRENT_ROLE }]
    EVENT 
    [IF NOT EXISTS]
    event_name    
    ON SCHEDULE schedule
    [ON COMPLETION [NOT] PRESERVE]
    [ENABLE | DISABLE | DISABLE ON SLAVE]
    [COMMENT 'comment']
    DO sql_statement;

schedule:
    AT timestamp [+ INTERVAL interval] ...
  | EVERY interval 
    [STARTS timestamp [+ INTERVAL interval] ...] 
    [ENDS timestamp [+ INTERVAL interval] ...]

interval:
    quantity {YEAR | QUARTER | MONTH | DAY | HOUR | MINUTE |
              WEEK | SECOND | YEAR_MONTH | DAY_HOUR | DAY_MINUTE |
              DAY_SECOND | HOUR_MINUTE | HOUR_SECOND | MINUTE_SECOND}
```

Este es un ejemplo de como quedaría un event que hace un update de un campo en la tabla mytable cada hora

```
CREATE EVENT myevent
    ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 HOUR
    DO
      UPDATE myschema.mytable SET mycol = mycol + 1;
```

[Aqui](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-event/) esta el enlace a la documentación

También cada que apagas el servidor se pierden los eventos que hayas creado

Answer (score 1):

Si tienes acceso al servidor hay varias cosas que puedes hacer.

Por ejemplo, crear tu propio cron con un script `SH` y controlar los tiempos en tu PHP:

```
# SH: Ejecuta cada minuto un script PHP
while sleep 1m
do
    php archivoCron.php #Controlar fechas y ejecución además de la lógica
done
```

Y ejecutarlo con `nohup ./script.sh &>/dev/null &`

---

O también directo en tu `archivoCron.php`:

```php
#!/usr/bin/php
// Ejecutar el 1ro de cada mes
while (1) {
    $d = date("d");
    if ( $d == "01" ){
        // La lógica del control de ejecución (evitar que se ejecute varias veces)
        // Código que debe ejecutarse
    }
}
```

Para ejecutarlo con `nohup ./archivoCron.php &>/dev/null &`

O mejor usar un administrador de procesos para cualquier opción.